# How to use java code to stop a websphere application

Tags: java, websphere

I'm trying to invoke the script from my java code on linux to stop a websphere application
my code is like

```
final String stopCmd = "wsadmin.sh -user wasadmin -password passw0rd -c \"AdminControl.invoke(AdminControl.queryNames('type=ApplicationManager,process=server1,*'),'stopApplication','myapp')\" -lang jython";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(stopCmd);
```

It works on Windows if I change wsadmin.sh to wasadmin.bat, but when it's linux, it just does not work...

Also, the command works from the command shell.

Any idea?

Comment: is the command string working if you run directly from command shell?

Comment: Yes, it works from command shell.

Comment: First things first. What user is starting the Websphere process (process owner)? Is the `wsadmin.sh` utility on the PATH for that user? Does he have permission to run `wsadmin.sh`? What exception or undesired behavior are you getting? `Process` just hangs? Does it echo anything back either to `output` or `error` streams?

Comment: Does your java code run on the Websphere container?